# The code to set/change the slice label for a line plot in DM script

Tags: dm-script

Try to find the code with function to set/change the slice label for a line plot in DM script, but could not find it.

I mean the codes could change the label "slice 1" to "ages" in a line plot with DM script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you seek is `ImageDisplaySetSliceLabelByID` and the example how to use it is:

```
image img := RealImage("Slice Demo",4,100,3)
img.ShowImage()
img = icol*(irow+random())
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
disp.ImageDisplayChangeDisplayType(3)
disp.LinePlotImageDisplaySetLegendShown(1)

OKDialog("Now rename slices")
number nSlices = disp.LinePlotImageDisplayCountSlices()
for( number i=0; i<nSlices; i++ )
{
    object id = disp.ImageDisplayGetSliceIDByIndex( i )
    disp.ImageDisplaySetSliceLabelByID( id, "entry #"+(i+1) )
}
```

> The examples section on Lineplot-displays in the F1 help is generally a good starting point for these things:

[image]

Comment: I tried to use “ object id = disp.ImageDisplaySetSliceLabelByID(id, “xxx”), it pops up “unable to match this argument list to any existing function”. Is this due to my DMv version is 3.01

Comment: and to my DM, there is no example script of "DataDisplay", the 1st is simple Image Computation, then it is Tags, TagGroup and TagLists. Not sure it is due to an offline version?

Comment: @together No, the offline version has nothing to do with it. GMS 3.01 ?? This is a very strange version. I would definitely recommend you update to the current latest version (3.3) There might be a but in GMS 3.0.1 (It was the very first release of GMS 3 and only available for a very short time.)

Comment: @together Just reread your commentd. You have used " object id = disp.ImageDisplaySetSliceLabelByID(id, “xxx”)," ? You can't use "id" as a parameter and return it as an object at the same time. Have you copy&pasted my examples and run it?

Comment: @together That's great. Could you then please also mark the answer as accepted? (What made the difference? A version update or a code change?)